# setting image max-height in print css

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an application that allows the user to upload a logo that will later be used while printing the page.  I need to display this logo in a way that will look ok regardless of the dimensions.  This is simple with web css, I set a max-width and a max-height and it looks fine with wide logos and tall logos. But when I print, the max settings are ignored.  I read somewhere that print css doesn't support the max-width and max-height attributes, so I figured there should be a work around somewhere but I can't find one.  This is my css for the image:

```
.print-contact .logo-img {max-width:60%;max-height:100px;float:left;display:inline-block;margin-right:15px;}
```

and the html

```
<tr><!-- other rows of tabular data --></tr>
<tr class="print-contacts-row">
    <td class="title">Questions?<br>Please Contact:</td>
    <td class="print-contact">
        <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
            <img class="logo-img" src="/logo" alt="logo"><br>
            <ul>
            ....<!-- more contact info -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This results in the image not being sized by css at all.  Rather it is scaled down to some unknown dimensions.  I can't be the first one to run into this problem so I'm surprised that I couldn't find some kind of work around.  Does anyone have a workaround to give an image a max height and max width while printing?  Any help would be appreciated.

The solution needs to support IE 11

Answer (score 1):

You can try out setting dimentions with width and height, make the image block element and then use `object-fit: cover;` or `object-fit: contain;` this might do the trick.

Edit for IE 11: You can make the logo to be printed as a CSS background with specific size of the element, no repeat and backgroind-size cover or contain? Replace img tag with a span or a div, and than with css you can give it width and height and make it as a background. You can embed the source for the image with inline css via the style atreibute. Will this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I should have mentioned that this needs to work in IE 11, and IE 11 doesn't support object-fit https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: @Sehael I edited the answer with a new idea, you can check it out.

Comment: This is close, but the problem is that there will always be a fixed box with specific dimensions so there is white space where there shouldn't be.  I'm not sure if there's going to be an ideal solution to this.

Comment: Width 100vw? Or 100%?

Comment: @Sehael Can you tell me where will be this white space? Because you can tell the element to get the full width of the page, and than make the background the full width of the element. The height must be fixed, but you can set it right and you won't have white space. The problem here will be with pixelation if the image is too small. Good luck! <: )>